# Is everything in Ext js blue?

Tags: javascript, css, extjs

Sure, the blue is nice and it has a nice office look but you wouldn't want all applications to have the same color. Is it easy customize the look in ext js?

Comment: @duffymo, yes, this is exactly what is css for, but question is how many additional step you have to take to achieve restyling. If you, for example, have a lot of images in you layout, even their repainting could be rather tedious task.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Theming Ext JS is much easier in 3.x than it was in 2.x. If you'd like to purchase a new theme, a new site has popped up with for-sale themes: [extthemes.com](http://extthemes.com/). You could even contact the developer if you'd like a custom theme built.

If you'd like to try it yourself, simply make a copy and rename `resources/xtheme-gray.css` and `resources/images/gray`, and start changing css!

One final option is to use the [Ext JS theme generator](http://github.com/extjs/extjs-theme), which is a ruby-powered development tool which is open sourced on github. This is very new and I'm really excited about it.

Comment: As of Jan-2013 exthemes.com is dead.  The Sencha market is where you need to go now: https://market.sencha.com/

Answer (score 1):

There is some built-in functionality for customization, however it's not the quickest thing to make a theme for it (and so there are only a few complete themes available).

However, [there are some themes the community is working on](http://blog.akawebdesign.com/index.php/2009/08/27/extjs-3-0-themes/), maybe one suits your taste?

If you want to try your hand at a color combination you like, you may want to give this a visit, closest thing to Theme Roller I've found for ExtJS: 
[ExtJS  Color Theme Changer](http://playground.ideashs.com/themescolor/)

Comment: @Upper Stage - I've used the jQuery theme roller a bit for a baseline style, the ExtJS for the same.  I haven't used the ExtJS equivalent in a production capacity to do 100% of my css though.

Answer (score 0):

We use the slate theme on a large project.  The customer likes it.  See the link provided by @Nick Craver.

To date, I have found it is not particularly easy to change the default look and feel of the more complex ExtJS components like grids or trees.  However, one of the reasons I like ExtJS is they provide complex, capable components out-of-the-box.  I usually stick to an existing theme when I plan to use these components.

Nothing prevents one from customizing components and ExtJS provides the low level utilities required to create anything.